# Why does Xcode misinterpret return type of Unirest API UNIHTTPJsonResponse header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, unirest

I am trying to compile example code for "Camfind" API but its failing on retrieving response header:

```
NSDictionary *responseHeaders = response.headers
```

Implicit conversion of a non-Objective C pointer type `int *` to `NSDictionary` is disallowed with **ARC**.

Here is my "podFile":

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'menswear' do
pod 'Unirest', '~> 1.1.3'
end

target 'menswearTests' do

end
```

Using this code to test compilation initially. Same as example provided from ["here"](https://www.mashape.com/imagesearcher/camfind).

```
 // These code snippets use an open-source library.
         NSDictionary *headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Key": @"7ze1l1nX1Wmshc4yBzHqeWBldlkhp1CfGcmjsnATkTf58N2F8b", @"Content-Type":   @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", @"Accept": @"application/json"};
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"focus[x]": @"480", @"focus[y]": @"640", @"image_request[altitude]": @"27.912109375", @"image_request[language]": @"en", @"image_request[latitude]": @"35.8714220766008", @"image_request[locale]": @"en_US", @"image_request[longitude]": @"14.3583203002251", @"image_request[remote_image_url]": @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/2d/Mashape_logo.png"};
    UNIUrlConnection *asyncConnection = [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:@"https://camfind.p.mashape.com/image_requests"];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSInteger code =  response.code;
        NSDictionary *responseHeaders = response.headers
        UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;
        NSData *rawBody = response.rawBody;
    }];
```

'headers' is a property of UNIHTTPResponse of which UNIHTTPJsonResponse extends.

```
@interface UNIHTTPResponse : NSObject

@property(readwrite) NSInteger code;
@property(readwrite, strong) NSDictionary* headers;
@property(readwrite, strong) NSData* rawBody;

@end
```

This seems like it should be very straight forward. I don't understand why Xcode is interpreting headers as `int *` despite what I see in `UNIHTTPResponse.h`.

Comment: Does the .m file giving the error import `UNIHTTPResponse.h`?

Comment: NSLog the headers before trying to assign it to the responseHeaders dictionary. If it is in fact a JSON response, then either typecast it or call dictionaryWithDictionary:

Comment: I'm pretty sure i've missed a step in setting up the cocoa pod correctly. The code seems correct.